# initialising h2o in Rstudio : not recognising 64-bit java

Tags: java, r, h2o

I work on Rstudio running on a dedicated linux server. I get an error initialising h2o:

```
> h2o.init()
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
<simpleError in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE): error in running command>
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
Please download the latest Java SE JDK 8 from the following URL:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

I checked the java config and got:

```
system("java -version")
openjdk version "1.8.0_77"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Apparently I have the good version of java. I have found people with similar problems on Windows. They were able to solve the problem by finding and indicating the good java path. However in the environnement I am working in, i am not sure how to do that.

Any idea on how to solve the problem ? to bypass the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set.  It may be pointing to the wrong spot, tricking H2O to find the wrong one.

You want JAVA_HOME/bin/java to be a good 64-bit java.

(The other thing you can optionally do is, when you do find a 32-bit java, uninstall it.  There is no real reason to have it unintentionally anymore these days; memory sizes are much bigger than 15 years ago.)

Comment: This is the general answer you can find here on stack overflow. My problem was more that i am working on a remote linux server and i could not easily manage / access the java intallation / path. The key to solve my problem was to navigate the file structure with: list.dirs(), starting with list.dirs("/usr/"), until I found java files. Then I tried multiple dirs until i found one that worked...